# Basic first order logic inference fails for symmetric binary predicate

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk, theorem-proving, first-order-logic

Super basic question. I am trying to express a symmetric relationship between two binary predicates (parent and child). But, with the following statement, my resolution prover allows me to prove anything. The converted CNF form makes sense to me as does the proof by resolution, but this should be an obvious case for false. What am I missing?

```
forall x,y (is-parent-of(x,y) <-> is-child-of(y,x))
```

I am using the nltk python library and the ResolutionProver prover. Here is the nltk code:

```
from nltk.sem import Expression as exp
from nltk.inference import ResolutionProver as prover

s = exp.fromstring('all x.(all y.(parentof(y, x) <-> childof(x, y)))')
q = exp.fromstring('foo(Bar)')
print prover().prove(q, [s], verbose=True)
```

output:

```
[1] {-foo(Bar)}                             A 
[2] {-parentof(z9,z10), childof(z10,z9)}    A 
[3] {parentof(z11,z12), -childof(z12,z11)}  A 
[4] {}                                      (2, 3) 

True
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `q=exp.fromstring('parentof(child_name, parent_name)` ?

Comment: @ArisF. In my example, the query, "q", is just something that is supposed to be false, which `foo(Bar)` certainly should be, but for some reason it is proved to be True.

Comment: Strange. The clause `{childof(z10,z9), childof(z10,z9)}` that you get when you apply resolution on `parentof()` is not equivalent to the empty clause. Instead it should be equivalent to `{True}`.

Comment: Looks like the ResolutionProver is unsound. The same example correctly fails with the TableauProver.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Thank you, that makes sense. For others looking at this, I believe that there was a slight typo in Dmitri's comment, applying resolution to `parentof()` gives `{childof(z10,z9), -childof(z10,z9)}` which is equivalent to {True}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick fix for the ResolutionProver.

The issue that causes the prover to be unsound is that it does not implement the resolution rule correctly when there is more than one complementary literal. E.g. given the clauses `{A B C}` and `{-A -B D}` binary resolution would produce the clauses `{A -A C D}` and `{B -B C D}`. Both would be discarded as tautologies. The current NLTK implementation instead would produce `{C D}`.

This was probably introduced because clauses are represented in NLTK as lists, therefore identical literals may occur more than once within a clause. This rule does correctly produce an empty clause when applied to the clauses `{A A}` and `{-A -A}`, but in general this rule is not correct.

It seems that if we keep clauses free from repetitions of identical literals we can regain soundness with a few changes.

First define a function that removes identical literals.

Here is a naive implementation of such a function

```python
import nltk.inference.resolution as res

def _simplify(clause):
    """
    Remove duplicate literals from a clause
    """
    duplicates=[]
    for i,c in enumerate(clause):
       if i in duplicates:
          continue
       for j,d in enumerate(clause[i+1:],start=i+1):
          if j in duplicates:
             continue
          if c == d:
               duplicates.append(j)
    result=[]
    for i,c in enumerate(clause):
        if not i in duplicates:
           result.append(clause[i])
    return res.Clause(result)
```

Now we can plug this function into some of the functions of the `nltk.inference.resolution` module.

```python
def _iterate_first_fix(first, second, bindings, used, skipped, finalize_method, debug):
    """
    This method facilitates movement through the terms of 'self'
    """
    debug.line('unify(%s,%s) %s'%(first, second, bindings))

    if not len(first) or not len(second): #if no more recursions can be performed
        return finalize_method(first, second, bindings, used, skipped, debug)
    else:
        #explore this 'self' atom
        result = res._iterate_second(first, second, bindings, used, skipped, finalize_method, debug+1)

        #skip this possible 'self' atom
        newskipped = (skipped[0]+[first[0]], skipped[1])
        result += res._iterate_first(first[1:], second, bindings, used, newskipped, finalize_method, debug+1)
        try:
            newbindings, newused, unused = res._unify_terms(first[0], second[0], bindings, used)
            #Unification found, so progress with this line of unification
            #put skipped and unused terms back into play for later unification.
            newfirst = first[1:] + skipped[0] + unused[0]
            newsecond = second[1:] + skipped[1] + unused[1]

            # We return immediately when `_unify_term()` is successful
            result += _simplify(finalize_method(newfirst,newsecond,newbindings,newused,([],[]),debug))
        except res.BindingException:
            pass
    return result
res._iterate_first=_iterate_first_fix
```

Similarly update res._iterate_second

```python
def _iterate_second_fix(first, second, bindings, used, skipped, finalize_method, debug):
    """
    This method facilitates movement through the terms of 'other'
    """
    debug.line('unify(%s,%s) %s'%(first, second, bindings))

    if not len(first) or not len(second): #if no more recursions can be performed
        return finalize_method(first, second, bindings, used, skipped, debug)
    else:
        #skip this possible pairing and move to the next
        newskipped = (skipped[0], skipped[1]+[second[0]])
        result = res._iterate_second(first, second[1:], bindings, used, newskipped, finalize_method, debug+1)

        try:
            newbindings, newused, unused = res._unify_terms(first[0], second[0], bindings, used)
            #Unification found, so progress with this line of unification
            #put skipped and unused terms back into play for later unification.
            newfirst = first[1:] + skipped[0] + unused[0]
            newsecond = second[1:] + skipped[1] + unused[1]

            # We return immediately when `_unify_term()` is successful
            result += _simplify(finalize_method(newfirst,newsecond,newbindings,newused,([],[]),debug))
        except res.BindingException:
            #the atoms could not be unified,
            pass

    return result
res._iterate_second=_iterate_second_fix
```

Finally, plug our function into the `clausify()` to ensure the inputs are repetition-free.

```python
def clausify_simplify(expression):
    """
    Skolemize, clausify, and standardize the variables apart.
    """
    clause_list = []
    for clause in res._clausify(res.skolemize(expression)):
        for free in clause.free():
            if res.is_indvar(free.name):
                newvar = res.VariableExpression(res.unique_variable())
                clause = clause.replace(free, newvar)
        clause_list.append(_simplify(clause))
    return clause_list
res.clausify=clausify_simplify
```

After applying these changes the prover should run the standard tests and also deal correctly with the `parentof/childof` relationships.

```
print res.ResolutionProver().prove(q, [s], verbose=True)
```

output:

```
[1] {-foo(Bar)}                                  A 
[2] {-parentof(z144,z143), childof(z143,z144)}   A 
[3] {parentof(z146,z145), -childof(z145,z146)}   A 
[4] {childof(z145,z146), -childof(z145,z146)}    (2, 3) Tautology
[5] {-parentof(z146,z145), parentof(z146,z145)}  (2, 3) Tautology
[6] {childof(z145,z146), -childof(z145,z146)}    (2, 3) Tautology

False
```

**Update:** Achieving correctness is not the end of the story. A more efficient solution would be to replace the container used to store literals in the `Clause` class with the one based on built-in Python hash-based sets, however that seems to require a more thorough rework of the prover implementation and introducing some performance testing infrastructure as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It looks like the quick fix was to switch from full resolution to binary resolution and add in factoring. Just curious if the equality is sufficient, in AIMA pg.347 `Propositional factoring reduces two literals to one if they are identical; first-order factoring reduces two literals to one if they are unifiable. The unifier must be applied to the entire clause. The combination of binary resolution and factoring is complete.`